# Factorial related sum

Tags: summation, special-functions, factorial, gamma-function

I noticed the following (nice!) identity:

$$
S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n k!k = (n+1)!-1.
$$

Of course it can be proved by induction, but I was curious if there is a direct way co *compute* it. My first try has been with Euler Gamma function:

\begin{aligned}
S_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n k\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}t\, e^{-t}t^k \\
&= \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}t\, e^{-t}\sum_{k=1}^n k t^k\\
&= \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}t\, e^{-t}\frac{(n t-n-1) t^{n+1}+t}{(1-t)^2};
\end{aligned}

then I have some difficulties to go on. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that you tried the hard way to miss an easy derivation.

Comment: Yes, but I'm still curious about how to perform that integral.

Comment: I would expand the big ratio in simple fractions and be glad to observe that the poles vanish. Then there would be a polynomial leading to a sum of Gammas, and after some painful computation and a nice identity on factorials, I would obtain $(n+1)!-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$k!k = k!(k+1-1)=(k+1)!-k!.$$ See how well the sum telescopes and everything cancel!